# I removed yum on f24. How do I easily reinstall it?

Tags: fedora, rpm, yum, dnf

I removed `yum` on Fedora 24. How do I easily reinstall it?

I have tried reinstalling using `rpm`. First I cannot find the rpm previously used (`dnf-yum-1.1.10-1.fc24.noarch`) and the rpms I get a lot of dependencies and sub dependencies.

I removed `yum` because it was not working after I re-partitioned my OS using `gparted`

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 24 does not need `yum`. You should use `dnf`.

In case you really need a `yum`, then install it with `dnf`:

```
sudo dnf install yum
```

Comment: I've already tried dnf and I get the error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'. it seems there is something wrong with dnf as well.

Comment: That is different question and looks like some network problem.

Comment: I ran dnf install yum again and I get error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @yushauzumo Is yum the _only_ thing you removed?

Comment: So this is what I remove dnf-yum-1.1.10-1.fc24.noarch.rpm as well as chrome and firefox. They were all kind of faulty.